# For each loop printing only twice

Tags: php, foreach

I am having following for each loop of my array:

```
<table class="poruke">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Od broja</th>
        <th>Tekst poruke</th>
        <th>Vreme primanja</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $val) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".substr($array[Message][$i]['From'], 0, -2)."XX</td>";
echo "<td>".$array[Message][$i]['MessageText']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$array[Message][$i]['FormatedReceiveTime']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$i++;
}
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However instead of printing all of the entries, my code only prints last two of them.
Is something wrong with my increment-er?

[image]

Comment: You're iterating over the entries in `$array` and then updating an index and trying to iterate over entries of some sub-array. You get two entries because presumably $array has two top level elements in it.

Comment: When i change to $val nothing is printed. when i do print_r($array) i see over 50 entries.

Comment: those might not be toplevel entries. It looks like you're trying to iterate over $array[Message] not $array

Comment: I am trying to iterate over FROM, MESSAGETEXT and FORMATEDRECEIVETIME

Comment: in your foreach you start an iteration over $array (rename that, since it's a horrible name) but inside your loop, with your index, you are iterating over the subarray $array[Message]. This, obviously, does not work. you should either be foreaching over $array[Message] and using val inside the loop without the redundant index or writing whatever is appropriate for the structure of your array which you have not provided. What you have written is just not how foreach can possibly work.

Comment: This works.
`foreach($array[Message] as $val) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".substr($val[From], 0, -2)."XX</td>";
echo "<td>".$val[MessageText]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$val[FormatedReceiveTime]."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}`

But what about `$i = 0;` ? I removed that and `$i++;`
It works, but how it even works without this? What is increment-er used for if not for this.

Comment: You don't need the 'incrementer'. You should read the PHP docs for 'foreach'

Comment: Funny this is i read about it 1000 times, but some things in php i just do not get.. In my one question people are forcing me to use 'incrementer' but now you say i do not need it.
I am confused, arrays are always the same, for me...

Comment: foreach iterates over the elements of an array or array expression. it puts the element in the variable you supply on every iteration. That's it. That's the whole point of foreach. You don't need a separate index for foreach.

Answer (score 1):

If you iterate over the sub-array that has multiple items in it, than $val will be set to as many items as you have (that you were trying to count up in $i), and you can display them.

```
foreach($array['Message'] as $val) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".substr($val['From'], 0, -2)."XX</td>";
    echo "<td>".$val['MessageText']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$val['FormatedReceiveTime']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```